# How To Put A Human Readable Note In WordPress Core File Code Editing?

Tags: php, wordpress

To Whom It May Concern:

I am a total newbie for coding, but since I am managing a few WordPress websites and compelled to edited some WordPress core files from time to time, so I am here to ask for help for my question as titiled.
For example, a programmer can do /*Lorum Ipsum*/ in CSS editing for human readable memo, so, how can one do this in WordPrsss core file editing?  Such as function.php?  Thank you for your attention.

Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Are you kidding ? comment in files which will be override in each updates ? and i think with myself why newbie need comment in complex codes.

but for your answer you could possible do it for php codes with forward slashes before your codes example :

```
// $patt = array ( '0'  => 'x', '1'  => '*' );
```

CSS:

```
/*----------------------------------*/
```

Html:

`<!--<tags> </tags>--->`

also with most of editor you can utilize ctrl + / for commenting purpose.

Comment: Hi, there are constant requirements for editing the function.php from the WordPress plugins author or certain specific functions, I surely hope I don't have to to coding though.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the top of the included `function.php` file gives you the answer:

```
/**
 * Main WordPress API
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/option.php' );

/**
 * Convert given date string into a different format.
 *
 * $format should be either a PHP date format string, e.g. 'U' for a Unix
 * timestamp, or 'G' for a Unix timestamp assuming that $date is GMT.
 *
 * If $translate is true then the given date and format string will
 * be passed to date_i18n() for translation.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $format    Format of the date to return.
 * @param string $date      Date string to convert.
 * @param bool   $translate Whether the return date should be translated. Default true.
 * @return string|int|bool Formatted date string or Unix timestamp. False if $date is empty.
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It looks to me it is as same as in CSS file editing, am I correct?